# Vue: How to pass multiple Props with a loop

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an Object with multiple properties.

And i want to pass this multiple Props in my component. Usually i know which props i want to pass and do it like this:

```
<component :prop1="object.prop1" :prop2="object.prop2" :prop3="object.prop3" />
```

But i want to pass the props without knowing how much props there are in my JSON Object. Like a loop:

```
<component :loopThroughMyProps="object" />
```

So that i get the same result. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need is

```
<component v-bind="object"/>
```

Then in component you will have props named as per object keys.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? ```Then in component you will have props named as per object keys.```

Comment: @PA-GW well, if you have object like this: `{a: b}` and pass it to the `v-bind` you will be able to access it inside component by calling `this.a`. No more code needed AFAIK.